# Why don't monitors have more pixels per inch?

Tags: display, lcd, pixels

72 ppi is nothing. And we have been stuck with this for 20 years. Why do we need to resort to stupid tech like anti-aliasing instead of resolving the core of the issue, more pixels per inch!!!

It is really surprising considering all the progress cpu's, video cards, etc. have made.

Comment: You may find http://hardware.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=10/04/23/0012218 interesting reading.

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase the question as: why don't monitors have more pixels per inch? That way it covers your question and isn't subjective ;-)

Comment: Why not dots per centimeter you insensitive clod :)

Comment: The metric system should be standard, sadly many people are too suborn to learn.

Comment: Actually, it has been 96 dpi since VGA.

Comment: @MrStatic Because the civilized world uses inches!

Answer (score 2):

It saddens me to say it, but the market doesn't demand it. If demand was high enough for manufacturers to make them profitably, they would. Until then, it will remain a niche market with niche pricing.

Many users are quite happy with low-res screens with large icons and fonts. On multiple occasions I've set users' screens to optimal LCD resolution only to have them come back to me and request I change it back down to the low res, blurry version because it's easier for them to read (or simply familiar with).

Comment: An excellent reason why web sites shouldn't be designed with fixed font sizes. Sadly again, many sites still are.

Comment: I have had a problem with a sysadmin in the past who would come along and change my screen so that everything was too small and I couldn't read what was on the screen. Blurry but readable is preferable to sharp but unreadable to me. Perhaps if Windows had been able to scale better to keep thins the same size on the screen (in inches rather than pixels) it wouldn't have mattered.

Comment: @Neal You can change the DPI in Windows.